# How to aggregate data ignoring same values?

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

Given I have the following `articles` collection:

```
[
   { "title" : "Title 1", "score" : 80 },
   { "title" : "Title 2", "score" : 85 },
   { "title" : "Title 3", "score" : 85 },
   { "title" : "Title 4", "score" : 90 }
]
```

How can I get the number of articles that have a score greater than 82, without counting the equal values (in the example: 85), using the aggregation framework (the result should be `2`)?
The idea is to get the rank of an article.

Is there a simpler solution than using a double aggregation (group scores in the first one, and then doing the count)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it seems I found the answer. Here is the solution:

```
db.articles.aggregate( [
  { $match: { score: { $gt: 82 } } },
  { $group: { _id: '$score' } },
  { $group: { _id: null, count: { $sum: 1 } } }
] );
```

Any other solution is welcome too, but this one seems to be pretty straightforward.